# python - insert values from one list into another at pre-defined spots

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

In Python (3.5), if I have a long list like this:

```
long_list = ['0','1','0','1','0','0'.'0'.'1','1','0']
```

and a shorter list equal in length to the number of '1's in the long_list, like this:

```
short_list = [8,7,6,5]
```

How would I create a new list that "inserts" the values of my short_list into my long_list at each of the indices where there is a '1', and for consistency's sake, "replaces" the '0's in the long_list with some number (say 99).

I could do this with an excruciating for loop, but it seems like there should be a way to do this more efficiently with a list comprehension, no?

```
# bad solution
new_list = []
x = 0
for i in range(len(long_list)):
    if long_list[i] == '0':
        new_list.append(99)
    else:
        new_list.append(short_list[x])
        x += 1
```

Desired output:

```
new_list = [99,8,99,7,99,99,99,6,5,99]
```

Comment: Are you sure there are always as many values in `short_list` as there are `'1'` in `long_list`?

Comment: Yes, for this application there are. The short list is derived from the long list. Probably too much information to explain the actual usage (the example above is a toy example based off of real data), but I'm sure that the short list has exactly as many values as there are '1's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn `short_list` to an iterator and use list comprehension get value from there for each `'1'`, else use fixed value:

```
>>> long_list = ['0','1','0','1','0','0','0','1','1','0']
>>> short_list = [8,7,6,5]
>>> it = iter(short_list)
>>> [next(it) if x == '1' else 99 for x in long_list]
[99, 8, 99, 7, 99, 99, 99, 6, 5, 99]
```

This obviously works only if `short_list` has the same amount or more elements as there are `1` on the `long_list`. Above has **O(n)** time complexity where **n** is the amount of elements in `long_list`. Note that this works the same for all kinds of iterables, `long_list` and `short_list` could have been generators and the end result would have been the same.

Comment: thanks, this works great and is very fast (took less than a second on my real "long_list" of 200,000+ items). I should use iterators more often.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have a problem with changing `short_list`, you can try the following using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[short_list.pop(0) if i == '1' else 99 for i in long_list]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> long_list = ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0']
>>> short_list = [8, 7, 6, 5]
>>>
>>> [short_list.pop(0) if i == '1' else 99 for i in long_list]
[99, 8, 99, 7, 99, 99, 99, 6, 5, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is the best way, but it requires no new variables.

```
[99 if long_list[i] == '0' else short_list[long_list[:i].count('1')]
 for i in range(len(long_list))]
```